# Java cannot find symbol for class project

Tags: java

```
private double taxsnl (double s)
{
return (s * 0.06)+s;
}

public double taxsnls (double s)
{
return taxsnl;
}
```

> BoardGames.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
>   return taxsnl;
>         ^
>    symbol:   variable taxsnl
>    location: class BoardGames
>   1 error

I just can't figure out whats wrong. If you need anymore code just ask ill be here

Answer (score 2):

This means you are trying to return a variable named `taxsnl` which is undefined.

```
return taxsnl;
```

If you intend to call `taxsnl` method with `s` as an argument you need to do :

```
return taxsnl(s);
```

Comment: ty very much I didnt notice that

Comment: Clarification: `taxsnl` could be variable, parameter or field. Since method is shown, and very short, we can rule out variable and parameter, but since rest of class is not shown, a field is a possibility.

Comment: @Andreas Correct. You are allowed to have fields and methods with the same name in a class in Java. Not a good idea though!